# I run the code of json they show me ' json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, python-requests

I run the code of json they show me 'json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) ' I try to solve it but the error will not resolve I have possibly tried all ways from Stackoverflow to get this issue solved, but to my dismay none of them really worked. this is my Json file I am thankful if you solve it

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

cookies = {
    'ali_apache_id': '11.176.98.54.1631265989513.140114.9',
    'acs_usuc_t': 'x_csrf=k7p_cl4olk6_&acs_rt=36293f34708a430c821a4ca07e803d5a',
    'intl_locale': 'en_US',
    'aep_usuc_f': 'site=glo&c_tp=USD&region=PK&b_locale=en_US',
    'xman_t': 'FOHJr9djOMXaEdvw1kAYHyv5iUqjyagGBTzi7X7grRL+ZQa+meDO3W/c+wuSREdo',
    'xman_f': 'Ywgi8TV8vXjF+PvocUY2HbYQQX/EgajRbsX4q2c841QFZOJmov03NEwWYTvIGCNCtayMaRFtFwQ7FvTrSc2H1YU7NYkQYrThQyAVDTC/votfo5fPajMilQ==',
    'AKA_A2': 'A',
    'aeu_cid': '50ea15ab75e44b3dbb852d6df2b9ce1f-1631265993863-09504-UneMJZVf',
    '_m_h5_tk': 'bdfe3c9c2c6fe1631be5b34d54199b59_1631268071763',
    '_m_h5_tk_enc': '596921b4dd3c303b5a207bb079aa7c5f',
    'xman_us_f': 'x_locale=en_US&x_l=0&x_c_chg=0&x_as_i=^%^7B^%^22aeuCID^%^22^%^3A^%^2250ea15ab75e44b3dbb852d6df2b9ce1f-1631265993863-09504-UneMJZVf^%^22^%^2C^%^22affiliateKey^%^22^%^3A^%^22UneMJZVf^%^22^%^2C^%^22channel^%^22^%^3A^%^22PREMINUM^%^22^%^2C^%^22cv^%^22^%^3A^%^222^%^22^%^2C^%^22isCookieCache^%^22^%^3A^%^22N^%^22^%^2C^%^22ms^%^22^%^3A^%^221^%^22^%^2C^%^22pid^%^22^%^3A^%^22178094261^%^22^%^2C^%^22tagtime^%^22^%^3A1631265993863^%^7D&acs_rt=36293f34708a430c821a4ca07e803d5a',
    'cna': '1xLCGfXwYCMCAba5nOfl0d0W',
    'xlly_s': '1',
    '_gid': 'GA1.2.348165194.1631266017',
    '_gac_UA-17640202-1': '1.1631266017.CjwKCAjwhOyJBhA4EiwAEcJdcWmdhnXaKuUC7gYfCXUsX2I6Y6ytD90aYc-UmwqFFFo0iAggC-yPLRoC33oQAvD_BwE',
    '_gcl_aw': 'GCL.1631266017.CjwKCAjwhOyJBhA4EiwAEcJdcWmdhnXaKuUC7gYfCXUsX2I6Y6ytD90aYc-UmwqFFFo0iAggC-yPLRoC33oQAvD_BwE',
    '_gcl_au': '1.1.1515443772.1631266017',
    '_ga': 'GA1.1.1411441980.1631266017',
    '_ga_VED1YSGNC7': 'GS1.1.1631266017.1.1.1631266052.0',
    'RT': '^\\^z=1&dm=aliexpress.com&si=659ef8f8-f9fa-4f38-914d-836900491136&ss=kte5nks5&sl=2&tt=11dk&bcn=^%^2F^%^2F1737ad5a.akstat.io^%^2F&ld=1ahm^\\^',
    'intl_common_forever': 'QS/6ZqA9VP5xuy6ZcWRiFj+g0sbMdX6RXcE7cLONGlylz1o8UPwgXw==',
    'JSESSIONID': 'E7E08043B36294C09FD15FE3FEE7B774',
    'l': 'eBgCStEmgI85D443BO5anurza77OUIRbzmFzaNbMiIncC6HO9Yvp0n-QcRS9CdKRJWXVGUYB415GxPetjerUJyMXCT2IrGrk_nLXCeTC.',
    'isg': 'BP39iTfVQCeOXuTLCz1IzOO0DFn3mjHszM8Zl79C59ZE9h8oh-uVvEPgoTKwqkmk',
    'tfstk': 'ceGFBIV8aBdF6XNWHWNyOlhzN2VdaVhoGpU8KALY0UcOaK2L0s4P2PVNGDnzDC2h.',
}

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.aliexpress.com',
    'sec-ch-ua': '^\\^Google',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '^\\^Windows^\\^',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://www.aliexpress.com/premium/bags-for-kids-free-shipping.html?trafficChannel=ppc&d=y&CatId=0&SearchText=bags+for+kids+free+shipping&ltype=premium&SortType=default&page=2',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7',
}

params = (
    ('trafficChannel', 'ppc'),
    ('d', 'y'),
    ('CatId', '0'),
    ('SearchText', 'bags for kids free shipping'),
    ('ltype', 'premium'),
    ('SortType', 'default'),
    ('page', '2'),
    ('origin', 'y'),
    ('pv_feature', '33045811649,4000543474692,32860963433,4001093067801,1005002951326320,4000246337447,1005003033049991,4001028116893,32889512439,1005001803953391,4001116595811,32858936790,1005003077136329,4001035634763,1005002908685260,32808280573,1005002770388876,1005002795950286,1005002553040906,4000293853148,4001027494406,1005002873283693,32843357766,1005003077804431,1005003242225804,32957653772,1005002989576679,1005002951816889,1005002001992032,1005003181762539,4000133802735,1005002924842910,1005002687265458,32951209040,1005002068582327,4000122273715,1005002723842296,1005003193459768,1005003042632440,32946986855'),
)
res=[]
r = requests.get('https://www.aliexpress.com/glosearch/api/product', headers=headers, params=params, cookies=cookies)

#NB. Original query string below. It seems impossible to parse and
#reproduce query strings 100% accurately so the one below is given
#in case the reproduced version is not "correct".
# response = requests.get('https://www.aliexpress.com/glosearch/api/product?trafficChannel=ppc&d=y&CatId=0&SearchText=bags+for+kids+free+shipping&ltype=premium&SortType=default&page=2&origin=y&pv_feature=33045811649,4000543474692,32860963433,4001093067801,1005002951326320,4000246337447,1005003033049991,4001028116893,32889512439,1005001803953391,4001116595811,32858936790,1005003077136329,4001035634763,1005002908685260,32808280573,1005002770388876,1005002795950286,1005002553040906,4000293853148,4001027494406,1005002873283693,32843357766,1005003077804431,1005003242225804,32957653772,1005002989576679,1005002951816889,1005002001992032,1005003181762539,4000133802735,1005002924842910,1005002687265458,32951209040,1005002068582327,4000122273715,1005002723842296,1005003193459768,1005003042632440,32946986855', headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
data=r.json()
for p in data["mods"]["itemList"]["content"]:
    res.append(p)

df=pd.json_normalize(res)
df.to_csv('kv.csv')
```

Comment: Try to print `r.status_code` or `r.text`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `cookies=` parameter from `requests.get`. It seems the session cookies aren't needed:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    "authority": "www.aliexpress.com",
    "sec-ch-ua": "^\\^Google",
    "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "^\\^Windows^\\^",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "referer": "https://www.aliexpress.com/premium/bags-for-kids-free-shipping.html?trafficChannel=ppc&d=y&CatId=0&SearchText=bags+for+kids+free+shipping&ltype=premium&SortType=default&page=2",
    "accept-language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7",
}

params = (
    ("trafficChannel", "ppc"),
    ("d", "y"),
    ("CatId", "0"),
    ("SearchText", "bags for kids free shipping"),
    ("ltype", "premium"),
    ("SortType", "default"),
    ("page", "2"),
    ("origin", "y"),
    (
        "pv_feature",
        "33045811649,4000543474692,32860963433,4001093067801,1005002951326320,4000246337447,1005003033049991,4001028116893,32889512439,1005001803953391,4001116595811,32858936790,1005003077136329,4001035634763,1005002908685260,32808280573,1005002770388876,1005002795950286,1005002553040906,4000293853148,4001027494406,1005002873283693,32843357766,1005003077804431,1005003242225804,32957653772,1005002989576679,1005002951816889,1005002001992032,1005003181762539,4000133802735,1005002924842910,1005002687265458,32951209040,1005002068582327,4000122273715,1005002723842296,1005003193459768,1005003042632440,32946986855",
    ),
)
res = []
r = requests.get(
    "https://www.aliexpress.com/glosearch/api/product",
    headers=headers,
    params=params,
)

# NB. Original query string below. It seems impossible to parse and
# reproduce query strings 100% accurately so the one below is given
# in case the reproduced version is not "correct".
# response = requests.get('https://www.aliexpress.com/glosearch/api/product?trafficChannel=ppc&d=y&CatId=0&SearchText=bags+for+kids+free+shipping&ltype=premium&SortType=default&page=2&origin=y&pv_feature=33045811649,4000543474692,32860963433,4001093067801,1005002951326320,4000246337447,1005003033049991,4001028116893,32889512439,1005001803953391,4001116595811,32858936790,1005003077136329,4001035634763,1005002908685260,32808280573,1005002770388876,1005002795950286,1005002553040906,4000293853148,4001027494406,1005002873283693,32843357766,1005003077804431,1005003242225804,32957653772,1005002989576679,1005002951816889,1005002001992032,1005003181762539,4000133802735,1005002924842910,1005002687265458,32951209040,1005002068582327,4000122273715,1005002723842296,1005003193459768,1005003042632440,32946986855', headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
data = r.json()
for p in data["mods"]["itemList"]["content"]:
    res.append(p)

df = pd.json_normalize(res)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     itemType         productId nativeCardType                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              sellingPoints productType                                                                                                                                                                                            image.imgUrl  image.imgWidth  image.imgHeight image.imgType  saleMode.saleMode saleMode.singlePieceSaleSingularUnit                        store.storeUrl  store.aliMemberId                         store.storeName  store.storeId                                                                                                                title.displayTitle                                                                                                                    title.seoTitle                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         p4p.clickUrl p4p.adTag.tagStyle.backgroundColor p4p.adTag.displayTagType p4p.adTag.tagText                            p4p.sessionId  evaluation.starWidth                                      evaluation.starUrl  evaluation.starRating  evaluation.starHeight trace.exposure.displayCategoryId trace.exposure.postCategoryId                trace.exposure.session_id     trace.exposure.selling_point trace.exposure.aem_p4p_exposure               trace.exposure.algo_exp_id            trace.detailPage.algo_pvid          trace.detailPage.aem_p4p_detail             trace.detailPage.algo_exp_id                 trace.click.algo_pvid trace.click.aem_p4p_click trace.click.haveSellingPoint                     trace.pdpParams.pdp_ext_f                                                                                                         trace.pdpParams.compareFields                               trace.pdpParams.afTraceInfo trace.utLogMap.formatted_price trace.utLogMap.original_price_type trace.utLogMap.x_object_type              trace.utLogMap.algo_pvid                trace.utLogMap.session_id     trace.utLogMap.selling_point trace.utLogMap.original_price_strategy trace.utLogMap.x_object_id trade.tradeDesc prices.pricesStyle prices.salePrice.formattedPrice  prices.salePrice.minPrice prices.salePrice.priceType  prices.salePrice.minPriceType prices.salePrice.currencyCode  prices.umpPrice
0   productV3     4001116595811  nt_srp_cell_g                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  [{'tagStyleType': 'default', 'tagContent': {'tagStyle': {}, 'displayTagType': 'text', 'tagText': '+ Shipping: US $12.41'}, 'sellingPointTagId': '885603359', 'group': 8}]          ad                  //ae01.alicdn.com/kf/He2337c9476c34a60a4f155f0c88cff29n/Children-School-bags-set-Girls-Primary-Backpack-Kids-school-backpcak-3-pcs-princess-schoolbags-kids-mochilas.jpg_220x220xz.jpg             220              220             0  single-piece_sale                                  set    //www.aliexpress.com/store/5835119          242173229                       Shop5835119 Store        5835119     Children School bags set Girls Primary Backpack Kids school backpcak 3 pcs princess schoolbags kids mochilas escolar infantil     Children School bags set Girls Primary Backpack Kids school backpcak 3 pcs princess schoolbags kids mochilas escolar infantil                                    //us-click.aliexpress.com/ci_bb?ot=local&a=227465052&e=pv8ijh234CQ0M2Yh9PEYdhPciBVDNKO4nN3jcaLp9IM2kLUev2wI-Jtc.rrQKUOqZ.jLYpg2MiL47tKueIYqkIfolojZOKuKuZp.jDZQzMWLt25uerbN7WhayJU0UTX9mtR1RY.ntpoE0lCiDyugJoNa1Ob6YgSb8BSy5S8h4-hsl61oFydaB8pBV4zYUke2XJh6c.Xjn7AIJJm6UEMsbTLVpFQtvEfLiSw0c03CAnJthuvs6Yga.FEnifp00LrchA0ddi5J9G9GYoGE4aToOa9vDyxT.GFiw2MHD4imhFAKfzQ6hkuVhc-F6vijuwatdi-GteNNN9zBKgonTG4cP3HVMMjoSU20vDdPeQJqbCHKodtsvVCW59Kh1T-8e1XGz.KQ5.W-Iga78Ak2kuRi5j1POyFBa8.RLir0Vw.73-GpUuELIfBtnyzI0MOM7zxuUoEJRO6dul3fa0JElXJvSgDg5YigRCoJy.iZ4uUy0iLJRb18VQ6Iy-sr5c7GzwZ2kUD8KNvVBg6JuVMMSQUqAg0SpyfpPRLk7QYen20n1HjayyjELH7yX3rHNle0isOeiHiaJF.VUiG-8ZTzk5TvbJGtkESDYYIiF8IWOpZMZhV.ib3UewyauVL9bv4zitUYDy0N0wGVi7NzQGF5KLmRFhZydaTB8znD0rGo84fEqRKBpSL1PMgfD28GFUYamYorDN4P.vRok56Q8UI5DGRx-tMUjRFJsEcxQGWPbRFGvzUw2Kso7XX6Utlsgar20WGq&ap=1&rp=1                   rgba(0,0,0,0.20)                     text                AD  202109100332295547137149682700046872547                  33.0  //ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1S2ffafvsK1Rjy0Fi762wtXXaS.png                    4.8                   30.0                                                         380520  202109100332295547137149682700046872547                        885603359                   4001116595811   7cabf6da-e299-427a-ae77-67b9d3a90d30-0  7cabf6da-e299-427a-ae77-67b9d3a90d30  202109100332295547137149682700046872547   7cabf6da-e299-427a-ae77-67b9d3a90d30-0  7cabf6da-e299-427a-ae77-67b9d3a90d30             4001116595811                         true  %7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2210000014524525098%22%7D    source:search-sku;itemId:4001116595811;formatted_price:US $22.54;is_freeshipping:null;freight_formatted_price:null;trade_order:278     4001116595811__pc__mainSearch__wVFea6c__1631269950647                      US $22.54                              offer                    productV3  7cabf6da-e299-427a-ae77-67b9d3a90d30  202109100332295547137149682700046872547                        885603359                                sku_opt              4001116595811        278 sold            default                       US $22.54                      22.54                 sale_price                              2                           USD             True
1   productV3       32858936790  nt_srp_cell_g                                                                                                                                                                   [{'tagStyleType': 'default', 'tagContent': {'tagStyle': {}, 'displayTagType': 'text', 'tagText': '+ Shipping: US $0.91'}, 'sellingPointTagId': '885603359', 'group': 8}, {'tagStyleType': 'default', 'tagContent': {'displayTagType': 'text', 'tagText': 'Free Return'}, 'sellingPointTagId': '1200013764', 'group': 8}]          ad                               //ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1AnTufHuWBuNjSszgq6z8jVXaN/printing-man-children-s-cute-anime-backpack-school-bags-for-teenagers-kids-boy-BackPack-for-Children.jpg_220x220xz.jpg             220              220             0  single-piece_sale                                piece    //www.aliexpress.com/store/2942199          230452018                  IGETBAG Official Store        2942199         printing man children's cute anime backpack school bags for teenagers kids boy BackPack for Children boy mochila infantil         printing man children's cute anime backpack school bags for teenagers kids boy BackPack for Children boy mochila infantil                        //us-click.aliexpress.com/ci_bb?ot=local&a=227465052&e=DuYI6.99Z3k0M2Yh9PEYdhPciBVDNKO4nN3jcaLp9IM2kLUev2wI-Jtc.rrQKUOqZ.jLYpg2MiL58KyKD36HsXbWhdEpP5lAuPCpDWMW9VMlohItvNzfCmhayJU0UTX9mtR1RY.ntpoE0lCiDyugJoNa1Ob6YgSbArT-iVM3ER6qtWZjvgV0LK4xer8-mLhztuQBfOz9SbAGuyDLC8KD4MIOUIqYFSW9epVfZx394Dj6wvchxMquS2YFaVAGaDI8Te55YzTH8SC0CJ74kEf3VSc5cF8sXtJaydcTqOCqpiN0ekcYRawifMwioD3GrKatIeaVkE4ynlOQGCn3KI2.FjCbnUshM.9x8VkyGMxEFym74Etc4a1viDtneN1mlDh8muwst.NvF8Kx3aCNJE7Iq6lu2C--nV5NeXUj49Barda6KmHkQadZlIaO2Y0LFit7wds7-nQf-dS-Iks1eX-HUAzqjDxJTOS2DN8dOIS2WrLgACtt6YTlGZkJOU9RgsP50NNGUd8E8p6op6GR0UOsn6h6bjVbNm5GAOQqYjxEUeHORzZ9CnM4RtrLKMQsfvJfesc2V7SKw56IeJokX9VSIb7xlPOTlO9ssgRLtUAv3fsFlNcMK1qlSkitF4IKS5KRYUokVJCMjUfdZcz0s1LLBY7-apsumKThSglbGlq.AF1Jx1bldGz-W3V67jkpLVnmOx090DmtcBK-cJES3y92yHALgieIpyjsZ3Um2406l9RYgaMKzZeXa.w6LHc6w7kqxtoC6CQyVbI_&ap=2&rp=2                   rgba(0,0,0,0.20)                     text                AD  202109100332295547137149682700046872547                   NaN                                                     NaN                    NaN                    NaN                                                         152401  202109100332295547137149682700046872547             885603359,1200013764                     32858936790   7cabf6da-e299-427a-ae77-67b9d3a90d30-1  7cabf6da-e299-427a-ae77-67b9d3a90d30  202109100332295547137149682700046872547   7cabf6da-e299-427a-ae77-67b9d3a90d30-1  7cabf6da-e299-427a-ae77-67b9d3a90d30               32858936790                         true        %7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2265303251160%22%7D        source:search-sku;itemId:32858936790;formatted_price:US $21.03;is_freeshipping:null;freight_formatted_price:null;trade_order:2       32858936790__pc__mainSearch__wFhUkbm__1631269950647                      US $21.03                              offer                    productV3  7cabf6da-e299-427a-ae77-67b9d3a90d30  202109100332295547137149682700046872547             885603359,1200013764                                sku_opt                32858936790          2 sold            default                       US $21.03                      21.03                 sale_price                              2                           USD             True
2   productV3  1005002822222105  nt_srp_cell_g                                                                                                                                                                   [{'tagStyleType': 'default', 'tagContent': {'tagStyle': {}, 'displayTagType': 'text', 'tagText': '+ Shipping: US $1.97'}, 'sellingPointTagId': '885603359', 'group': 8}, {'tagStyleType': 'default', 'tagContent': {'displayTagType': 'text', 'tagText': 'Free Return'}, 'sellingPointTagId': '1200013764', 'group': 8}]          ad                                //ae01.alicdn.com/kf/Hf32442ffb7734eb1af79741f02cc74c6k/Pikurb-Comedy-Cartoon-Sanchez-Smith-Backpack-School-Notebook-Travel-Bag-Gifts-for-Kids-Friends.jpg_220x220xz.jpg             220              220             0  single-piece_sale                                piece  //www.aliexpress.com/store/911787716          251338914                            Pikurb Store      911787716                                    Pikurb Comedy Cartoon Sanchez Smith Backpack School Notebook Travel Bag Gifts for Kids Friends                                    Pikurb Comedy Cartoon Sanchez Smith Backpack School Notebook Travel Bag Gifts for Kids Friends                        //us-click.aliexpress.com/ci_bb?ot=local&a=227465052&e=PVTW7U2UY.o0M2Yh9PEYdhPciBVDNKO4nN3jcaLp9IM2kLUev2wI-Jtc.rrQKUOqZ.jLYpg2MiJ1HtAbJnl9fKgnODWt.UWeiR7fjgLCFNOxJ0MFRRWSdWhayJU0UTX9mtR1RY.ntpoE0lCiDyugJoNa1Ob6YgSbzOUEXrLEZerR0qAweJ2ajxoGCbqVcqGNy06wwyCdtEC20K8ndaaAmUSt.FVjJ4ssiSw0c03CAnLSWxJW33OYjkefCbL9fnIzhA0ddi5J9G9GYoGE4aToOa9vDyxT.GFiw2MHD4imhFAKfzQ6hkuVhc-F6vijuwatdi-GteNNN9zBKgonTG4cP3HVMMjoSU20vDdPeQJqbCHKodtsvVCW59Kh1T-8e1XGz.KQ5.W-Iga78Ak2kuRi5j1POyFBa8.RLir0Vw.73-GpUuELIfBtnyzI0MOM7zxuUoEJRO6dul3hi548lB1t8njHffVGHbb5uOD2c7rHvziTMCJ5khBITVHXdlPkmQUbh5ItiyUBfYCyIXdG80YugOBGfCXRFLPbt-71uk6qPiKunI4Hqk-jT-hAa.T0lgdYTNSrecyKsdG9eH.VGfEr8A0P09acv3GSo1aGItwNadwkLN1xiG9SxbUwSLs16YiBc6dW3EYJz-lN8vAqO6c2lEl8ESJODzk0Bi9SOizE8yv327zWybcMVCnF8d.fLCYqSKc1qzYzXQAR7NzE-bfKnOxPUCN5ppGelzyR1jOvuo6ewKuHGBdrKArqJl1om0PncWT.XYbs91I_&ap=3&rp=3                   rgba(0,0,0,0.20)                     text                AD  202109100332295547137149682700046872547                   NaN                                                     NaN                    NaN                    NaN                                                         152401  202109100332295547137149682700046872547             885603359,1200013764                1005002822222105   7cabf6da-e299-427a-ae77-67b9d3a90d30-2  7cabf6da-e299-427a-ae77-67b9d3a90d30  202109100332295547137149682700046872547   7cabf6da-e299-427a-ae77-67b9d3a90d30-2  7cabf6da-e299-427a-ae77-67b9d3a90d30          1005002822222105                         true  %7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000022838930937%22%7D   source:search-sku;itemId:1005002822222105;formatted_price:US $24.09;is_freeshipping:null;freight_formatted_price:null;trade_order:0  1005002822222105__pc__mainSearch__5BHFVSG__1631269950647                      US $24.09                              offer                    productV3  7cabf6da-e299-427a-ae77-67b9d3a90d30  202109100332295547137149682700046872547             885603359,1200013764                                sku_opt           1005002822222105             NaN            default                       US $24.09                      24.09                 sale_price                              2                           USD             True
3   productV3     4000990052073  nt_srp_cell_g                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          [{'tagStyleType': 'default', 'tagContent': {'tagStyle': {}, 'displayTagType': 'text', 'tagText': 'Free Shipping'}, 'sellingPointTagId': '885603359', 'group': 8}]          ad                                    //ae01.alicdn.com/kf/H6c87b4f1601548269b050f696b5a07f6k/Doctor-Toys-for-Children-Set-Kids-Wooden-Pretend-Play-Kit-Games-for-Girls-Boys-Red-Medical.jpg_220x220xz.jpg             220              220             0  single-piece_sale                                piece    //www.aliexpress.com/store/3116101          230933542                  LYONAVA Official Store        3116101        Doctor Toys for Children Set Kids Wooden Pretend Play Kit Games for Girls Boys Red Medical Dentist Medicine Box Cloth Bags        Doctor Toys for Children Set Kids Wooden Pretend Play Kit Games for Girls Boys Red Medical Dentist Medicine Box Cloth Bags                                            //us-click.aliexpress.com/ci_bb?ot=local&a=227465052&e=21pi3RSMwLg0M2Yh9PEYdhPciBVDNKO4nN3jcaLp9IM2kLUev2wI-Jtc.rrQKUOqZ.jLYpg2MiK1ZyitkmInnzbtA1VMcplukIp5awqob8ofr7o6BM-w3mhayJU0UTX9mtR1RY.ntpoE0lCiDyugJoNa1Ob6YgSbzOUEXrLEZeojh40FSA1-RwajD-74GjS1wjcVoeY1LvkVMm0oqy9OjQWlUsiHTpyAAa4a06yo9Ov5q8LUoa2II.q.6BVcpM2CG6qzQQxPAYkW8UuNrWi3biPbrCLli.elx7DhFOOnSmZysOtk9dV3gnaGxeREWKPUkc1wehWII2Mqbd1GkOsi5rvdC4USJ3-NCfzkkY3R7WljA8fdyxpY3aTRsnptZ1Zh5suwC2JE74rS6rvKkgNFOoBkb9oYb5xDTKw31dzlB0kGaeTk0bSPWWu0NbmqtHZh6z07cf71XS1x7EnRelXrnG1SHYV5jBXU0fWV-zXQFdkVeOEw00tjTmGbmz8B7NOCUeTTQwIeAI0taa2MN8pjHZW-1Vr2ZyuEVekxPZiot8E5DHCQ7aIPatQ.ypLGufedU35btroCmI6z78.sr7wFKVhMTvfrH5BqSK0XggpLkpFhSiRUkIyNR91lzPSzUssFFId5dIpEHVlKCVsaWr8AXUnHVuV0bP5bdXruOSktWeY7HT3QOa1wEr5wkRLfL3bIcAuCJ4inKOxndSbbjTqX1FiBowrNl5dr.DosdzrDuSrG2gLoJDJVsg__&ap=4&rp=4                   rgba(0,0,0,0.20)                     text                AD  202109100332295547137149682700046872547                  33.0  //ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1S2ffafvsK1Rjy0Fi762wtXXaS.png                    4.8                   30.0                                                      100001742  202109100332295547137149682700046872547                        885603359                   4000990052073   7cabf6da-e299-427a-ae77-67b9d3a90d30-3  7cabf6da-e299-427a-ae77-67b9d3a90d30  202109100332295547137149682700046872547   7cabf6da-e299-427a-ae77-67b9d3a90d30-3  7cabf6da-e299-427a-ae77-67b9d3a90d30             4000990052073                         true  %7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2210000013207037926%22%7D    source:search-sku;itemId:4000990052073;formatted_price:US $26.23;is_freeshipping:null;freight_formatted_price:null;trade_order:705     4000990052073__pc__mainSearch__Y8gP1NF__1631269950647                      US $26.23                              offer                    productV3  7cabf6da-e299-427a-ae77-67b9d3a90d30  202109100332295547137149682700046872547                        885603359                                sku_opt              4000990052073        705 sold            default                       US $26.23                      26.23                 sale_price                              2                           USD             True
4   productV3  1005002821756978  nt_srp_cell_g                                                                                                                                                                   [{'tagStyleType': 'default', 'tagContent': {'tagStyle': {}, 'displayTagType': 'text', 'tagText': '+ Shipping: US $1.97'}, 'sellingPointTagId': '885603359', 'group': 8}, {'tagStyleType': 'default', 'tagContent': {'displayTagType': 'text', 'tagText': 'Free Return'}, 'sellingPointTagId': '1200013764', 'group': 8}]          ad                  //ae01.alicdn.com/kf/H2c419a38465942fb9b9d404a886452deE/Pikurb-Bassa-Football-Superstar-Messi-Students-Backpack-Schoolbag-Notebook-Travel-Bag-Gifts-for-Kids-Friends.jpg_220x220xz.jpg             220              220             0  single-piece_sale                                piece  //www.aliexpress.com/store/911787716          251338914                            Pikurb Store      911787716                      Pikurb Bassa Football Superstar Messi Students Backpack Schoolbag Notebook Travel Bag Gifts for Kids Friends                      Pikurb Bassa Football Superstar Messi Students Backpack Schoolbag Notebook Travel Bag Gifts for Kids Friends                                    //us-click.aliexpress.com/ci_bb?ot=local&a=227465052&e=yFMCvIjek3M0M2Yh9PEYdhPciBVDNKO4nN3jcaLp9IM2kLUev2wI-Jtc.rrQKUOqZ.jLYpg2MiJ1HtAbJnl9fKgnODWt.UWeiR7fjgLCFNMlohItvNzfCmhayJU0UTX9mtR1RY.ntpoE0lCiDyugJoNa1Ob6YgSbzOUEXrLEZeoe66IewY2kj5jOhOUBTtjDsdJBCE0vkxxNlVCaqerrRPPFbnafiF4sXegB9GkPDnWZ9YPnalwrue.6fiQGZcuJik0KD5pDvFgbqrNBDE8BiRbxS42taLduI9usIuWL96XHsOEU46dKZnKw62T11XeCdobF5ERYo9SRzXB6FYgjYypt3UaQ6yLmu90LhRInf40J.OSRjdHtaWMDx93LGljdpNGyem1nVmHmy7ALYkTvitLqu8qSA0U6gGRv2hhvnENMrDfV3OUHSQZp5OTRtI9Za7Q1uaq0dmHkXZptBsqyWR8AkxdxwqOn6dMTN2Jn9aQC3thEpDyPUAKDrF8wOUmFsaQs8s-SYIC6Jue3URzLBOyGdw9sSAhJld0Orn482HxrykJrVPujH927Ow2ls.GbtyHBbgsbIJOCixdE2MBqoH8aKJa.A7XTy.cTKOIpq6zMUTWCtUNkKVL9bv4zitUYDy0N0wGVi7NYUKWn1zZguBZydaTB8znD0rGo84fEqRKBpSL1PMgfD28GFUYamYorDN4P.vRok56Q8UI5DGRx-tMUjRFJsEcxQGWPbRFGvzUw2Kso7XX6Utlsgar20WGq&ap=5&rp=5                   rgba(0,0,0,0.20)                     text                AD  202109100332295547137149682700046872547                   NaN                                                     NaN                    NaN                    NaN                                                         152401  202109100332295547137149682700046872547             885603359,1200013764                1005002821756978   7cabf6da-e299-427a-ae77-67b9d3a90d30-4  7cabf6da-e299-427a-ae77-67b9d3a90d30  202109100332295547137149682700046872547   7cabf6da-e299-427a-ae77-67b9d3a90d30-4  7cabf6da-e299-427a-ae77-67b9d3a90d30          1005002821756978                         true  %7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000022837165040%22%7D   source:search-sku;itemId:1005002821756978;formatted_price:US $24.09;is_freeshipping:null;freight_formatted_price:null;trade_order:1  1005002821756978__pc__mainSearch__hidlevi__1631269950647                      US $24.09                              offer                    productV3  7cabf6da-e299-427a-ae77-67b9d3a90d30  202109100332295547137149682700046872547             885603359,1200013764                                sku_opt           1005002821756978          1 sold            default                       US $24.09                      24.09                 sale_price                              2                           USD             True

...
```

Comment: when we  import into csv file again they show same error json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 2)

Comment: @ArslanAziz Maybe you've received captcha response? check `print(r.text)`

Comment: when print(r.text)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\CaptainCazRepo\src\up.py", line 42, in <module>
    print(r.text)
  File "E:\python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufe0f' in position 4933: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Cookies needed, enter same url to browser, grab cookies, also test for: assert '<html>' not in resp.text, 'need  to renew captcha'

Comment: Also before parsing you need: resp = html.unescape(resp) and dropping non ascii chars